Java Turtle moves/turns 1 pixel/degree at a time. So far good but I'm missing something?

The turtle can rotate at a speed of 1° per second. The speed of the turtle's movement is a unit distance ("1 pixel") per second. The turtle cannot move and rotate at the same time. At the same time, in order to still see the road, the turtle only moves forward (i.e., it does not turn). Let C be a point at the coordinates [x,y]. What is the shortest time in seconds for the first turtle to reach point C? Remember that the turtle can rotate both clockwise and counterclockwise.


Add the timeToArrival method to the TurtlesWorld class. The timeToArrival method takes 2 parameters x, y - the coordinates of point C, and returns the smallest time in seconds that any of the turtles can get to point C.

The problem is that when I paste it to check it in course evaluator the values differ
So far I defined my method to:

cycle through array of Turtles
get their distances and angles towards the point
If angle is higher than 180 (angles are taken by another method that takes only clockwise angle)
then change angle to angle = 360 - angle;
Since it's rotation and movement is 1 second at a time it's 1:1 so we add rotations needed and distance to the time taken
We compare times to find out which is shortest each time
Return best time

I feel like there's fallacy in my thought but I can't put my finger directly on it
Would it be step 3 or 4? Considering that it's decimal numbers in distance and degrees
public double timeToArrival(double x, double y) {
    double angTo;
    double time = 0;
    double bestTime = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.turtles.length; i++) {
        this.turtles[i].setDirection(0);
        this.turtles[i].penDown();
        angTo = this.turtles[i].directionTowards(x, y);
        distTo = this.turtles[i].distanceTo(x, y);
        // angle integer is arbitrary because I had the turtles move to see whether they
        // reach the point (they do)
        int angle = 1;
        if (angTo > 180) {
            angTo = 360 - angTo;
            angle = -1;
        }
        time += angTo + distTo;

        if (time < bestTime) {
            bestTime = time;
        }
        time = 0;
    }
    return bestTime;
}


can we assume that directionTowards() is actually returning how much the turtle must rotate? That is, the difference between current direction and target direction, not just the target direction?

some problems with posted code: 1) missing declaration of distTo; 2) why the time is being accumulated +=  in time += angTo + distTo? Is there something not posted?! 3) Is setDirection(0) correct?

What library is this using?

Hello Wrath Of Parking Lot, Could you show us the Turtle class?.

If the turtles are holograms, then your thought process looks good. But, if they are physical beings and cannot be at the same point at the same time, then you need to check for collisions. You should think of whether all the turtles are moving towards the point, or only the closest one and you will need to compute each turtle's each step and avoid collisions in each moment of your prediction if collision is a thing. Otherwise, if we ignore turtle collision, then yup, the time is (turn_steps + movement_steps) seconds for each and you are looking for the minimum value. And, of course, a turtle should turn first and then move. If the turn would be more than 180 seconds, then it is the wrong direction and the turtle needs to turn the other way around.
